# White block when opening Javadoc`s on IntelliJ IDEA after installing theme

Tags: intellij-idea

I've updated my IntelliJ IDEA and after the update the javadoc`s became almost useless, as a big white block:

[image: Javadoc with Monokai theme]

However, when I use any default theme from the IDE, it works just fine:

[image: Javadoc with Darcula theme]

This is happening to any non default theme in IntelliJ IDEA.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-263380) caused by the custom color scheme not inheriting Darcula and instead inheriting the white background Default scheme.

The solution is to either edit the scheme .xml file to make in inherit Darcula or to change the documentation background color:

[image: documentation bacgkround]